# How to add google webfonts to mediawiki?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, webfonts

google web fonts requires that an HTML *link* element should be added to the *head* of the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
```

I cant find the proper php file to modify.

Im using mediawiki 1.17, with the default skin "vector".

Comment: solved, I can use @import _url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif&v1);_ in a css file, there's no need to modify any php files.

Answer (score 4):

You may also try this mediawiki extension: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WebFonts It  does not use google fonts, but you can add custom fonts

Answer (score 3):

You can modify `SkinVector::setupSkinUserCss` in `skins\Vector.php` and append `$out->addStyle($fonturl, 'screen');` to it.